# Funcionamento Lista Encadeada

Tags: python-3.x, lista-encadeada

Estou tentando implementar um esquema de lista encadeada em Python e estava debugando o código para entender melhor o funcionamento da mesma. Estou curioso em alguns aspéctos.

O código que estou implementando é o seguinte:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = None

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def set_data(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def get_next_node(self):
        return self.next_node

    def set_next_node(self, next_node):
        self.next_node = next_node

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)


class List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.first_node = None
        self.last_node = None

    def insert_at_last_node(self, value):
        new_node = Node(value)
        if self.is_empty():
            self.first_node = self.last_node = new_node
        else:
            self.last_node.set_next_node(new_node)
            self.last_node = new_node

    def insert_at_first_node(self, value):
        new_node = Node(value)
        if self.is_empty():
            self.first_node = self.last_node = new_node
        else:
            new_node.set_next_node(self.first_node)
            self.first_node = new_node

    def remove_first_node(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise (IndexError, 'Lista vazia!')
        pop_value = self.first_node.get_data()
        if self.first_node == self.last_node:
            self.first_node = self.last_node = None
        else:
            self.first_node = self.first_node.get_next_node()
        return pop_value

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.first_node is None

    def __str__(self):
        string = ''
        value = self.first_node
        while value is not None:
            string = string + str(value.get_data()) + ' -> '
            value = value.get_next_node()
        return string
```

Primeiro aspécto:

Na função `insert_at_last_node`, quando eu aciono o método `set_next_node` na variável `self.last_node`, por qual motivo a variável `self.first_node` também é atualizada?

Segundo aspécto:

Para a seguinte modificação na função `insert_at_last_node`:

```
def insert_at_last_node(self, value):
    new_node = Node(value)
    if self.is_empty():
        self.first_node = new_node
    else:
        self.first_node.set_next_node(new_node)
```

Por qual motivo a variável `self.first_node` não adiciona todos os valores devidos como era feito na situação anterior do código?

É possível observar esses comportamentos ao executar o seguinte script em um arquivo paralelo:

```
from nodes import List

new_list = List()
new_list.insert_at_last_node(5)
new_list.insert_at_last_node(4)
new_list.insert_at_last_node(3)
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugestão: coloca um print(self) dentro da função da inserção da lista, para você conseguir acompanhar melhor o comportamento dela:

```
def insert_at_last_node(self, value):
    new_node = Node(value)
    print(self)
    if self.is_empty():
        self.first_node = self.last_node = new_node
    else:
        self.last_node.set_next_node(new_node)
        self.last_node = new_node
```

Fazendo a inserção como a que você indicou, dos valores 5, 4 e 3, a saída do programa será:

```
5 ->
5 -> 4 ->
5 -> 4 -> 3 ->
```

O que está correto, ele só atualiza o first_node e o last_node ao mesmo tempo, como você disse, quando a lista estava vazia e você quer inserir o primeiro elemento, e nesse caso realmente, ele será o primeiro e o último, por ser o único ali dentro.

Já na sua segunda pergunta, essa alteração na função `insert_at_last_node` você está fazendo apenas duas alterações na lista:

1. Apontando qual é o primeiro nó, caso a lista esteja vazia (if)
2. Trocando o valor do próximo do primeiro, caso a lista tenha algum valor(else)

Em outras palavras, essa sua lista não vai passar de dois elementos, sendo que toda vez que você tentar inserir mais que isso ele vai apenas trocar o valor do último. Essa seria a saída dessa lista (inserindo 5, 4, 3, 2, 1):

```
5 ->
5 -> 4 ->
5 -> 3 ->
5 -> 2 ->
5 -> 1 ->
```

Quando deveria ser:

```
5 ->
5 -> 4 ->
5 -> 4 -> 3 ->
5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 ->
5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 ->
```

Quando você quer inserir um nó ao final de uma lista encadeada os passos são atualizar o próximo do que é atualmente o último para o que você quer inserir (antes ele apontava para None) e atualizar que o último agora é esse novo nó, o que já ocorre nesse trecho de código que você forneceu:

```
self.last_node.set_next_node(new_node)
self.last_node = new_node
```